# Does it matter what kind on project to start for hello world?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

It is my first day with iOS development. I got Xcode and all the other things. Then I created a new project.  Many of the tutorials I found online recommended starting a windows-based application, but I didn't see it so I started a page-based application instead.

What is the difference between them? Maybe my version of the things I downloaded is newer than the ones in the tutorials?

Also, my dev interface has .h and .m files.  The code there looks equally foreign to me at the moment.  Where do I start programming? :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with single view template. You can test controls and UI elements on the single view that has been created for you.

Also the h means the header and the m means the implementation. in the h you announce the public elements of the class. in the m you implement them.

this tutorial should be helpful:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/1797/how-to-create-a-simple-iphone-app-tutorial-part-1

Answer (score 4):

I personally would start with an empty application and learn to add things in.  With the new version of Xcode and the new Storyboard API, it is super easy to add a new storyboard and add view controllers, etc.  I have a couple of tutorials on [irockios.com](http://irockios.com), but the tutorials on Lynda.com, the Stanford videos (iTunesU) and Ray Wenderlich are great resources to learn.  To go over some of the differences between the templates:

- Master Detail - this is going to give you a Storyboard with a Navigation Controller and 2 View Controllers (a master which will be a TableViewController and a detail view which will be a regular ViewController.  You will also have the option of adding in the Core Data stack (iOS's object oriented DBMS).
- Open GL Game - Template for making a game (I have never used this).
- Page Based - Gives you a Page View Controller and a Root View Controller and Data View Controller.  This gives you a page turning based UI (I don't use this)
- Single View - A common one.  Gives you a Storyboard with one View Controller and one Scene.  Downside to using this template is there is no option to include the Core Data stack.  While CD is not something a beginner will use, IT IS something you will want to get used to including.  If you continue doing iOS development, you will use it later on.
- Tabbed App - Gives you  a Tab Bar Controller with two View Controllers (one for each tab).  Like the Single View - no option for including the Core Data Stack.
- Utility App - Used for a flip view style UI.  Core Data is an option here, although I can't see why.
- Empty Application.  My favorite.  Core Data is an option and adding a Storyboard is easy enough.  Getting used to starting with this is something you will need to learn to do if you are going to make iOS development something you do lots.  The [tutorial](http://irockios.com/?p=32) on irockios.com deals with using the empty template and having a tabbed, nav controller based app with core data in less than 10 minutes.  This is how I develop apps.

I personally would start off with Lynda.com courses (the ones by Simon Allardice are good), and the Stanford iTunesU course (latest one), and then also look through Ray Wenderlich's site for tutorials.

Answer (score 2):

To start objective-c, you should start with command line tools, which are programs entirely text-based programs. To start a command-line project, you open Xcode and the window should pop up with the option to create a new project. Then, go to the sidebar on the left and click application under Mac OS X. From there, click on Command Line Tool. The product name section is the name of the project. I recommend checking the Automatic Reference Counting box. Also, make sure that the you select **Foundation** in the **Type** drop down menu.

You should start with command line tools to learn the basic syntax and design patterns of objective-c, as when you advance to iPhone Applications, you must learn the ins and outs of many frameworks. The template I recommend to begin with is the Single View Application template.

Hope this helps.

P.S. I agree with Micheal in that you should buy some books with you are unfamiliar with Objective-C. My personal favorite is Programming in Objective-C 4th Edition by Stephan Kochan. It's very comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

RayWenderlich.com will become your best friend for its tutorials. They're kept up to date and you can vote on the ones you want to see next.

Specifically I'd start here at this brand new tutorial to get your objective C off the ground. http://www.raywenderlich.com/12444/objectively-speaking-a-crash-course-in-objective-c